# nvme SSD mount as single mount point centos 7

Tags: ssd, centos, nvme

I have 4 nvme SSD drivers which directly attached to motherboard which showing as 4 jbod drivers to OS.

How can i mount this as single mount point?

Kindly advise

Answer (score 2):

The same way as with other disk types:

- either use LVM to join all physical disks to a single logical volume,
- or set up a RAID across all disks,
- or use a multi-device filesystem such as zfs.